# jsPlumb Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="-Infinity"

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I've dynamically created a jsPlump graph

```
jsPlumb.ready(function(){
    jsPlumb.setContainer('row');

    var endPointLeft = {
      maxConnections : 1,
      onMaxConnections: function(info, e){
        alert('Max. 1');
      },
      connector: ['Straight'],
      anchor: 'Right',
      endpoint: 'Dot',
      isSource: true,
      isTarget: true
    };

    var endPointRight = {
      maxConnections : 1,
      onMaxConnections: function(info, e){
        alert('Max. 1');
      },
      connector: ['Straight'],
      anchor: 'Left',
      endpoint: 'Dot',
      isSource: true,
      isTarget: true
    };

    jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('.leftTree tbody').children().filter('.left'), {}, endPointLeft);
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint($('.rightTree tbody').children().filter('.right'), {}, endPointRight);

    // delete connection when clicked on
    jsPlumb.bind('click', function (connection, e) {
        jsPlumb.detach(connection);
      });
  });
```

But every time I connect two dots, I get the following error "Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="-Infinity" " and "Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="-Infinity"".

Does somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? jsPlumb seems to work fine for me with static layouts, but anything involving the layout changing via javascript causes `jsPlumb.connect` to throw the error you described.

Comment: your code seems ok. can you provide an example HTML?